# Use $(this) in an external function

Tags: jquery

I have a question more out of curiosity. I have written the following code

```
function checkBox() {
if($(this).prev().is('.click-animation')) {
   TweenMax.to(this, 0.5, {
       background: 'red'
   });
} else {
    TweenMax.to(this, 0.5, {
        background: 'green'
    });
}
```

}

```
$('.click-animation').on('click', function() {
    checkBox();
});
```

And this way it will not activate. Possibly because it cannot define `$(this)` and I'd like to know why.

Now the function works if I just past it inside the click event it's only when I take it to an outside function that it does nothing.

So why does it not recognize `$(this)` and what can I do to use it if I were to use an outside function.

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried using `$('.click-animation').on('click', checkBox);`?

Comment: You need to pass `this` also as a parameter to the function.

Comment: You may pass `this` as parameter to the function like `checkBox(this);`.

Comment: @secelite, you could, but that value won't be bound to `this` inside `checkBox()`.

Comment: http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi indeed. When using `this` as a parameter the function have to be adapted accordingly.